# Can you you show a grey hint in an HTML text box with CSS alone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, label

You see these text input boxes from time to time on the web: a grey label is shown inside the box, but once you type there, the grey text disappears. This page even has one: the "Title" field behaves exactly like that.

So, questions:

1. Is there a standard term for this? I'm really struggling to find anything on google
2. Can it be done with just CSS?
3. Failing that, can it be done with localised JavaScript? (ie, code just within the  tag, not in the HTML header).

Comment: Not sure if there's a universally accepted term for this, but at least the Windows API calls these [cue banners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775793%28VS.85%29.aspx#cue_banner).

Comment: It should be the input box's default value.  CSS-only [no], JavaScript [yes]

Comment: @casablanca Placeholder text should be a better term

Comment: @Yi Jiang: That sounds reasonable too, though I guess Microsoft's intention with calling them cue banners was to suggest that the text is a cue to the user telling them what to enter.

Comment: ah, using the term "cue banner" helps find this near-duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156966/how-can-i-position-a-label-inside-its-textfield

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"placeholder"` attribute is [now supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) across all major browsers.

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text">
</form>​
```

Styling it still seems to require vendor prefixes:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #59e;
}    
input:-moz-placeholder {  
    color: #59e;  
}
​
```

Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/bGrQ4/2/

Comment: Thanks for this. Works fine in up-to-date browsers. The accepted reply is a little bit outdated. Or use this directly with inlined CSS for general cases: <input type="text" name="name" style="-webkit-input-placeholder: color: #555;" placeholder="enter stuff here"/>

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to do it with CSS. But looking at the page source, SO is doing it thusly-wise:

```
<input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" 
       onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" 
       type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">
```

The middle line starting with "onfocus" is where the work is happening. When the text field gets focus, it checks to see if the default value ("search") is there. If so, it sets the value to '' (empty string). Otherwise, the text is unaffected.

One potential issue here is that if someone is trying to search for the word "search", then clicks outside of the box and clicks back in again, the text gets reset. Not a huge issue, but something to keep in mind as you're working.

Comment: I'm surprised SO actually does it this way. A better method would be to use a flag instead of directly comparing the text.

Comment: @casablanca There are some questionable front end things in the SO source - probably done for speed of development over long term maintainability.

Comment: @casablanca - SO doesn't care for standards or best practices. Tables are used everywhere, even in places where lists would be better. Inline Javascript too, even when it's trivial to do otherwise.

Comment: I would guess that they've been busy with other things.  those boys don't exactly sit still...

Comment: I agree. SO can have some pretty weird code. Based off of the code, if you are searching for "search" and you accidentally click out of the textbox, next time you click it, it will be blank.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - It may not be as un-DRY as it seems. It's possible they have something on the server-side that generates search boxes, and it's easy to change a line or two of their backend code to update every search box at once.Who knows? Unless Jeff or somebody comes out and tells us, I'm just speculating.

Comment: @Aaron - You might be right about the search box, but tables for list... come on, surely there's no excuse for using that! The code's almost the same, but with lists you get both better semantics and less markup.

Comment: My guess is that they don't really care, the ad-revenue is making them rich.  If it's working and it's not less-secure, why invest time, money, or stress?  Also, as stated before SO programmers are not the best - they've had bigger problems injection hacks.

Answer (score 6):

The standard name is watermark input.

follow this page if you are interested in JQuery
http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

If you want this with HTML + CSS *only*, you can try using the new HTML5 `placeholder` input attribute. Unfortunately this attribute is not widely supported, so try using a script such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect browser support for this feature for a feature such as this.

I would not recommend using inline Javascript for this - it's bad practice and goes against the principle of separation of content and behavior. Using jQuery, for instance, something like this will work:

```
var input = $('input[name="search"]');
var placeHolder = input.attr('placeholder');

input.val(placeHolder);

input.focus(function(){
    this.value = '';
}).blur(function(){
    if(this.value === '') this.value = placeHolder;
});
```

Comment: It's more complicated than that.  What happens if the form is submitted before a user enters a value in the input?  Your hint is submitted...so make sure to account for it.  Also if doing form validation, need additional logic to check for empty fields.  etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's an HTML built-in for new browsers.

Just use the "placeholder" attribute:

< input id="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Hint Text Here" >

Answer (score 1):

1. I call them input labels. don't know if it is a standard
2. Nope - you could if they were allowed child elements like so

```
input {
    position: relative;
}

input label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

input:focus label {
    display: none;
}
```

But you can't have children of inputs (AFAIK), so it **won't work**.

1. Yes, see the link above (using jQuery, but trivially done without)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already found the answer you are looking for but for others this may help

```
<script>
    function inputFocus(i){
        if(i.value==i.defaultValue){ i.value=""; i.style.color="#000"; }
    }
    function inputBlur(i){
        if(i.value==""){ i.value=i.defaultValue; i.style.color="#888"; }
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<input type ="text"onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" value="Some Text"/>
```

hope this helps